# Robocopy script skipping files

Tags: robocopy

I have a robocopy script that's skipping all files even though I'm specifically telling it to move PDF and CSV files and directories recursively. Directories are being created. Can someone help me solve this and I don't get why this is happening.

```
robocopy "\\servername\quote_docs" "\\domain\share" *.pdf *.csv /e /move /MAXAGE:1 /r:3 /log+:C:\robocopyERS\robolog.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This was because the test files generated by a third party had a created date of 2015. This conflicted with Maxage